# Laravel 5.4 update user profile not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I am trying to update the profile of the user who is logged in. I like to create a function that the user that has logged in when he/she wants to update or edit his/her own profile. So I got no errors. But the problem is it wont update and it just refresh my browser but nothing happens.

Here is the code on my controller

```
public function edit($id)
    {
        // $applicant = $this->applicantRepository->findWithoutFail($id);

        $applicant = Applicant::where('id',$id)->get()->last();

        if (empty($applicant)) {
            Flash::error('Applicant');

            return redirect(route('applicant.home'));
        }

        return view('applicant-dashboard.edit')->with('applicant', $applicant);
    }

    public function update($id, UpdateApplicantRequest $request)
    {
        $applicant = $this->applicantRepository->findWithoutFail($id);

        if (empty($applicant)) {
            Flash::error('Applicant not found');

            return redirect(route('applicant.home'));
        }

        $input = $request->all();

        $applicant = $this->applicantRepository->update([
            'name' => $input['name'],
            'address' => $input['address'],
            'cellphone_no' => $input['cellphone_no']], $id);

        Flash::success('Profile updated successfully.');

        return redirect(route('applicant.edit'));
    }
```

Here is the code in my routes:

```
Route::get('/edit/{id}', 'HomeController@edit')->name('applicant.edit');
    Route::post('/update', 'HomeController@update')->name('applicant.update');
```

Here is the code in my views:

**edit.blade.php**

```
@extends('applicant-dashboard.layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <section class="content-header">
        <h1>
            Applicant Profile
        </h1>
   </section>
   <div class="content">
       {{-- @include('adminlte-templates::common.errors') --}}
       <div class="box box-primary">
           <div class="box-body">
               <div class="row" style="padding-left: 20px">
                   {!! Form::model($applicant, ['route' => ['applicant.update', $applicant->id], 'method' => 'post']) !!}

                        @include('applicant-dashboard.fields')

                   {!! Form::close() !!}
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
@endsection
```

and in **fields.blade.php**

```
{!! Form::hidden('id', null, ['class' => 'form-control input-sm','required']) !!}

<!-- Name Field -->
<div class="row" style="padding-right: 15px">
<div class="form-group col-sm-4">
    {!! Form::label('name', 'Name:') !!}
    {!! Form::text('name', null, ['class' => 'form-control input-sm','required']) !!}
</div>
</div>

<div class="row" style="padding-right: 15px">
<!-- Address Field -->
<div class="form-group col-sm-4">
    {!! Form::label('address', 'Address:') !!}
    {!! Form::text('address', null, ['class' => 'form-control input-sm','required']) !!}
</div>
</div>

<!-- Cellphone Field -->
<div class="row" style="padding-right: 15px">
<div class="form-group col-sm-4">
    {!! Form::label('cellphone_no', 'Cellphone:') !!}
    {!! Form::text('cellphone_no', null, ['class' => 'form-control input-sm','required']) !!}
</div>
</div>

<div class="row" style="padding-right: 15px">
<!-- Submit Field -->
<div class="form-group col-sm-12">
    {!! Form::submit('Save', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) !!}
    <a href="{!! route('applicant.home') !!}" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</a>
</div>
</div>
```

code in my model for validation:

```
public static $rules = [
        'name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|unique:applicants',
        'password' => 'required',
        'password_confirmation' => 'required|same:password'
    ];
```

and the **UpdateApplicantRequest.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use App\Models\Applicant;

class UpdateApplicantRequest extends FormRequest
{

    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return Applicant::$rules;
    }
}
```

I am looking for help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you should you cross check validation request i.e UpdateApplicantRequest. Please check whether you are sending all the required parameters or not.

Comment: yes I had return the rules in my models in my UpdateApplicantRequest but still not working

Comment: Can you show me code from that file?

Comment: wait I'll edit my answer

Comment: @nikhil_gandhi here sir

Comment: See you have commented email and password field in your  controller but in model it is required. That's why you are being redirected and it's not updating.

Comment: @nikhil_gandhi oh wait sorry. I will not update the email and password thats why I commented it. I will want only to update the name address cellphone no. Even if I uncommented it. It's still not working. Sorry for that

Comment: you also have password_confirmation as required field in your model.

Comment: okay I get it. So I would create another rule for update validation?

Comment: yes exactly... :)

Comment: but if I uncommented all the fields that is required it is still the same nothing still happens.

Comment: Remove server side validation and than check. I am sure problem lies there only, rest of the code is okay.

Comment: Thankyou it already works! I have created a new validation using switch statement depends on the method. Btw Thankyou very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be several options. Firstly you need to make sure that right url mapping is created, secondly if the validation is not failing and thirdly if any other middleware is redirecting, for example user is not logged in.

Change the beginning of update method to be

```
public function update($id, Request $request) {
dd($request->all());
```

If you do not see dd() output then mapping is not right. If you see then validation fails.

Check `php artisan route:list` and see what middleware is assigned to this route.

Right now it looks like email and password are missing from the fields. Usually you have different validation rules when creating and when updating.

Also I advise to have displaying validation errors in your template.